# UIActivityViewController doesn't post images to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

When I use UIActivityViewController to post an image to Facebook, it goes through the motions but the post never shows up. Image posts to Twitter work fine; non-image posts to Facebook work fine. SLComposeViewController ditto.

Oddly comforting: I see the same problem trying to share photos from Camera.app or Photos.app, so apparently it's not just me, and I've had another user confirm. Yet IIRC, this was working maybe last week.

Any ideas? Wait for Apple and or Facebook to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for Apple/Facebook worked, as of this morning.